# What customers who bought the biggest amount of a product in one order?

Tags: sql, aggregation

I have 2 tables:

- `CUSTOMERS` (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS);
- `ORDERS` (ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, DATE_ORDER DATE, ID_CUSTOMER, AMOUNT);

Get the first and last names of the customers who bought the biggest amount of a product in one order.

The orders without customer should not be considered. Please sort by FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME

```
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.id_customer
GROUP BY customers.firstname
HAVING (SELECT MAX(orders.amount) FROM orders);
```

What I'm doing wrong? thx

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what does "of a product" mean?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one customer with the largest value of `amount`, then simplest method is `order by` and then fetching only one row:

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname 
from customers c join
     orders o
     on c.id = o.id_customer
order by o.amount desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want the biggest amount *per product*, then window functions are the right approach

```
select pc.*
from (select o.product, c.firstname, c.lastname, o.amount,
           rank() over (partition by o.product order by o.amount desc) as seqnum
      from customers c join
           orders o
           on c.id = o.id_customer
     ) pc
where seqnum = 1;
```